# My first browser Ajax call to Node JS server (does'n work)

Tags: node.js, ajax

Reading here and there (mostly on stackoverflow) I created my first node server:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

If I use Google Chrome form the URL it works perfectly:

[image]

But If I use a simple client side html page with some ajax code it does not show nothing:

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <style media="screen">
    body {
      font-family: Helvetica;
      text-align: center;
    }

    #birthday-greeting {
      font-size: 72px;
      color: red;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
      <h1>Today's your special day!</h1>
      <button id="reveal" onclick="sendTheAJAX()" class="button">Why's that?</button>
      <div id="ajax-content">
      </div>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function sendTheAJAX() {
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      //xmlhttp.open("GET","https://codepen.io/eclairereese/pen/BzQBzR.html", true);
      xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost:3000/", true);
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
          str = xmlhttp.responseText
          alert(str);
          document.getElementById('ajax-content').innerHTML = str;
        }
      }
      xmlhttp.send();
      document.getElementById('reveal').style.display = 'none';
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

Also consider that if I substitute my localhost node URL http://localhost:3000/ with another found on the web: https://codepen.io/eclairereese/pen/BzQBzR.html
It works!

So it must be something in my Node server...

Thanks in advance for any help you may provide

Any tips

Comment: You're sure the server is running while you're doing this? Secondly, can you add a log in the app.get of your server and another one in the callback of your AJAX and tell us the result please?

Comment: If via browser works means that the server is running

Comment: Maybe you shut it down before using your Ajax script. What about the logs? Does the request reach your server? Does the answer reach your callback?

Comment: Open developer tool of browser, in console tab you can find what happen is going on. I guest, you have to config `cors` for your server.

Comment: hoangdv you are right! On the Chrome console I can read the following error message: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the comment by hoangdv the solution consist in adding CORS support on the node server .

Here you can find a good explanation: [Handling CORS in Express by Flavio Copes](https://flaviocopes.com/express-cors/)